# How to get the number of tracks from playlist?

Tags: android, audio, cursor, playlist, mediastore

Can anyone tell me how to get the number of members of playlist? I tried this but it does not work:

```
int PlayListCount = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._COUNT));
```

It throws this exception:

```
llegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.
Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```